# Why is glibc (and maybe others) static tm struct not thread local?

Tags: c, thread-safety

So was doing a peer review today, and someone complained about the use of gmtime in the form `tm tm = *gmtime(&t)`. My assumption had always been that it would use a per-thread storage to make it safe but having looked around seems `time/localtime.c` just declares it as a regular global.

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/localtime.c;h=38f3123d9a4093c3bbd78e4d39f63491af1fed56;hb=master

```
/* The C Standard says that localtime and gmtime return the same pointer.  */
struct tm _tmbuf;
```

If I understand correctly this makes that implementation totally broken on modern systems, because it is not practical to reliably tell what other threads are doing?

Why is it not made per-thread, making it as safe as it could ever have intended to be?

I realise of course there are other versions of this function (although not portable), so a simple mygmtime wrapper is possible, but seems odd this is still an outstanding issue.

Comment: I suspect an oversight (since things like `errno` *are* thread-local) --- either on the part of POSIX (if they *explicitly* declare it must be static, because they forgot to update), or on the part of GNU (if POSIX does not say so, and they are allowed to do that --- might be an oversight). If it's the latter, I'd recommend filing a bug.

Comment: As for the non-portable functions, I take it you're talking about `gmtime_r` and friends. Those are SUS, but (sadly) not stdC. In Windows (being the usual exception), you have `_gmtime_s` (note the reversed order of arguments!), though `gmtime` *does* use thread-local storage there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the `gmtime()` and `localtime()` functions are not thread safe.  There are quite a few such functions in the C library, and they are as they are because they were designed for single-threaded programs (which once was the only kind), and changing them to rely on thread-local data would be an alteration to their previously-defined semantics.  They are not "totally broken" because many programs use only one thread, and because with proper care they can be used in multithreaded-programs, too.

With that said, these are among the many functions for which reentrant versions have been standardized (`gmtime_r()` and `localtime_r()`); if the reentrant versions are available to you then they are a better choice for multithreaded programs.

Comment: I diasgree regarding changing them --- `errno` was changed to thread-local, with few to no issues. As for C, since C before C11 had no concept of threads at all, you could argue that the semantics in a threaded environment were *already* implementation-defined (or even unspecified).

Comment: Can you be sure a program only has one thread in the presence of external components (e.g. .so's)? Not sure on Linux, but on Window's there seems to always be extra threads from "somewhere" (e.g. on a app I tested I got a "PGHook.dll" thread somehow).

Comment: @FireLancer, you can normally be confident about (non-)multithreading based on what functions and libraries your program uses, at least on Linux and other POSIX systems.  It is abnormal for undocumented threads to be created in your process on such systems, where "abnormal" pretty much means "unheard of".  A function or library that created such a thread on the sly and allowed it to have any visible side effects on other threads would certainly be considered buggy on that account.

Comment: @TimČas, the only explanations I see are (1) the standards committee intentionally chose to avoid requiring a change to the existing semantics of these functions, and (2) the standards committee was packed with ignorant screw-ups.  Although I cannot rule out (2), I find (1) a far more believable explanation.  Feel free to offer other alternatives if you have any.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Probably a mix of both, really. A case in point for (2): The existance of `<tgmath.h>` before C11 (meaning, without `_Generic`). Apparently done because the std comittee was envious of Fortran's success in the field of numeric computing, and wanted to make C more Fortran-y.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The thing I miss the most in C stdlib *are* reentrant variants of its functions. 2nd top spot for me is no standarized way of defining custom callbacks for `FILE` (meaning, every single lib implements its own --- like `SDL_RWops` for SDL). A standarized `FILE` structure (at least semi-, in the form of "it must start like this, but may contain other members *AFTER* these") + user callbacks would've removed the need for that.

Comment: @TimČas, I feel your pain.  Especially with respect to `FILE`.  I would dearly love to be able to implement custom streams that could be used with the standard library's stream i/O functions, but there's just no good way to do it.  (So I, too, end up writing wrappers.)